# Python Taylor series sin function graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a Taylor series sin(x) graph using python with Jupyter notebook. I created a short function. The graph will appear correctly until `y2`, but it will fail at `y3`. It is difficult to draw a graph with a value of `x = 2.7` in `y3`. I don't know how to fix `y3`.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x) :
   result = x - x**3/6 + x**5/120 
   return result

x = np.linspace(0.0, 7.0, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
y2 = x - x**3/6 + x**5/120
y3 = f(2.7)

plt.title("taylor sin graph")
plt.xlim(0, 7+0.2)
plt.ylim(-5, 5+1)

plt.plot(x, y, label='sin(x)')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='x=0')
plt.plot(x, y3, label='x=2.7')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want to add `y3` here:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. What is y3 supposed to be? In your code, it's a single value, the function calculated in 2.7. Now, if you plot a single point, you get a single dot on the plot, which will be nearly invisible.

Comment: `f` is returning a single value. Doing `f(2.7)` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to happen with `y3 = f(2.7)`.  This will only return a single value.  If you use `y3 = f(x)`, then you will get the identical plot that you get for `y2`.

Comment: @ChrisMueller: May be the OP wants just to highlight the value at one point

Answer (score 1):

After your comment, it got clarified that you do not need a single point but a horizontal line. In that case you can simply input an x-mesh which has the same value `2.7`.

To do so, you first define an array containing values `2.7` by using `np.ones(100) * 2.7` and then just pass it to the function.

```
y3 = f(2.7*np.ones(100))
plt.plot(x, y3, label='x=2.7')
```

[image]

For plotting a single point at `x=2.7`, there are two ways (among possible others).

**First option** is to just specify the two x-y numbers and plot using a  marker as

```
plt.plot(2.7, y3, 'bo', label='x=2.7')
```

**Second option** is to use `plt.scatter`. `s=60` is just to have a big marker.

```
plt.scatter(2.7, y3, s=60, label='x=2.7')
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to make your option 1 values lists? `plt.plot(2.7, y3, 'bo', label='x=2.7')` works

Comment: @Bazingaa thankyou for help! and i have another question.  How do I make a graph of x=2.7 in one line that doesn't break like an x=0 or sinx graph? How should I fix the function?

Comment: @uenbh: What do you mean? Do you mean horizontal line?

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks, I edited. I still kept the list thing as one possibility but moved it to additional option

Comment: @Bazingaa yes. I want to compare the Taylor approximation polynomial graph.
I want to make x=2.7 graph a long line graph format rather than a dot. I want it to be expressed in the same format as sin or x = 0 graph.

Comment: @uenbh: I edited my answer. Check it and let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x) :
   result = x - x**3/6 + x**5/120 
   return result

x = np.linspace(0.0, 7.0, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
y2 = x - x**3/6 + x**5/120
y3 = f(2.7)

plt.title("taylor sin graph")
plt.xlim(0, 7+0.2)
plt.ylim(-5, 5+1)

plt.plot(x, y, label='sin(x)')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='x=0')
plt.plot(2.7, y3, label='x=2.7', marker=11)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You have to add point - not an array in x-axis and scalar on y-axis.

Comment: i have another question. How do I make a graph of x=2.7 in one line that doesn't break like an x=0 or sinx graph? How should I fix the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
plt.plot([2.7], [y3], '-o', label='x=2.7')
```

would work. You can't plot(x,y3) when x is a linspace and y3 is just one number.

Also, Taylor approximation of sin function works only in the interval (-pi, pi).